# How to deploy static and dynamic files in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

my file structure looks like this

```
-project-root
-functions // firebase functions
-public
 - Admin // dynamic contents
  - assets // folders like js css images
  - admin.html / sample file for admin login page
 - User // static contents
  - assets // folders like js css images
  - index.html / sample file for my static welcome page
- firebase.json
```

when i set up my firebase.json hosting into
`"public": "public/User",` all my files under that folder works fine and i know that it would not deploy any files under Admin folder.

But when i set the hosting into:
`"public": "public",` it cannot find my index.html under User folder. But when i change the url path extension with `/Admin/admin.html`, it reads my contents under that folder.

For reference this is my firebase.json file :

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/User/welcome.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/Admin/**",
        "destination": "/Admin/admin.html"
      }   
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false, 
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(json)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

My index.html file under User folder has a href link connected to admin.html file under Admin folder

I checked all the path and it works fine in localhost.

Note that on my web project I only use public template.

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot find my index.html under User folder"?  What exactly are you doing that suggests Firebase Hosting is doing something other that what you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear how someone can reproduce the issue.